# curl says OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN in connection to s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, libcurl

I am trying to download a file over https TLS from aws using libcurl.
I am using below options

```
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_CONTROL); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cert.pem");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256");
```

and I get the below output when I try to connect.

```
*   Trying 52.219.158.33...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com (52.219.158.33) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: cert.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN in connection to s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0*
```

but when I try to do the same thing using curl command line it works fine

$curl --cacert cert.pem  -o final.bin -v

I get a detailed output below

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 52.219.66.33...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com (52.219.66.33) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: cert.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [91 bytes data]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [5304 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Mar 26 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Mar  5 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com" matched cert's "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /<url> HTTP/1.1
> Host: s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: g/Q+ZRBzQktcquk2elmt1j5fA6w+WCJtJert44SXh4oeEGIZ6y55OcClxQwN/P+QaznzcMjjo=
< x-amz-request-id: MF91MY53D47PST6
< Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 08:27:39 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Nov 2021 09:47:49 GMT
< ETag: "33fd329aa6dsf3cdfcf9d7e010c3485e2"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
< Server: AmazonS3
< Content-Length: 6304448
< 
{ [5 bytes data]
100 6156k  100 6156k    0     0   322k      0  0:00:19  0:00:19 --:--:--  485k
* Connection #0 to host s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com left intact
```

How do I get the same output using libcurl APIs?
Any other configuration is missing as part of curl config?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such cipher TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for OpenSSL listed in the manual [SSL Ciphers](https://curl.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html). This caused the attempt to use TLS with the empty list of ciphers. You would know it if you had checked the returned value of `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256")`. The curl dump shows you the correct cipher.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256");
```

Additionally, `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_CONTROL)` has no affect. [CURLOPT_USE_SSL](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USE_SSL.html) is for the protocols FTP, SMTP, POP3, IMAP.